# Why does Phase-locking value show spurious effects at the beginning & end of a signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, phase, time-domain

I am trying to understand the behaviour of the phase-locking-value, as e.g. defined [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1741-2552/aacfe4/pdf), by some simple examples.

Basically, I am creating two signals with the same frequency & amplitude, where the phase-offset between the two is random. Now, as expected, at most time points the PLV gives me a low value indicating that there is not a consistent pattern of phase onset. However, at the beginning & end of the signal, there are some strange effects. I suppose that these might be somehow introduced by the Hilbert transform, or is this a problem with my implementation?

Here is how I defined the function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plv(x,y,trial_axis=0):

    hilbert_x = signal.hilbert(x)
    hilbert_y = signal.hilbert(y)
    
    normed_x = hilbert_x/np.absolute(hilbert_x)
    normed_y = hilbert_y/np.absolute(hilbert_y)
    
    
    p = np.absolute(np.mean(normed_x*normed_y.conj(),axis=trial_axis))
    
    return p
```

Here we have a plot of the behaviour:

```
t = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
N = 50
s_1 = np.array([np.sin(10*2*np.pi*t) for i in range(N)])
s_2 = np.array([np.sin(10*(2*np.pi*t)+np.random.uniform(low=0,high=2*np.pi) ) for i in range(N)])
p = plv(s_1,s_2)
plt.plot(p)
```

[image: PLV over time]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a side effect of your hilbert transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was previously posted as an answer should have been an extended comment -- sorry for that. There simply was not enough space for what I thought I'd write about how the Octave code seemed to behave. Now that the code is cleared, what should have been the answer in the first place (given the rather obvious signs), is now the answer: spectral leakage.

The Hilbert transform is calculated by zeroing half the FFT of the signal and then recomputing the analytical signal through the IFFT. Brute-force zeroing will always lead to some leakage due to the nature of the limited length of the data. This can be easily tested with your code. `s1` is a simple `sin()`, so its Hilbert transform will be a `-cos()`. Simply plot the difference between `-cos()-hx.imag`, and you'll see the leakage. The same goes for the second signal.

This is the changed code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = 10
t = np.linspace(0, 100/f, 1000)
N = 50f = 10
nt = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 100/f, nt)
N = 50
hor = np.ones(nt)
ver = np.ones(N)
r = np.array( [ np.random.uniform(low=0, high=2*np.pi) for i in range(N) ] )
s1 = np.array( [ np.sin( 2*np.pi*f*t ) for i in range(N) ] )
s2 = np.array( np.sin( 2*np.pi*( f*ver[:,None]*t + hor*r[:,None] ) ) )
c1 = -np.array( [ np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t) for i in range(N) ] )
c2 = -np.array( np.cos( 2*np.pi*( f*ver[:,None]*t + hor*r[:,None] ) ) )
hx = signal.hilbert(s1)
hy = signal.hilbert(s2)
nx = hx/np.absolute(hx)
ny = hy/np.absolute(hy)
p = np.absolute( np.mean( nx*ny.conj(), axis=0 ) )
plt.plot(p)
plt.show()
```

and this is the test (`c2` will show non-overlapping plots due to the randomness):

```
plt.plot(c1.transpose() - hx.imag.transpose())
plt.show()
```

[image: leak]

The Octave code, for checking:

```
f = 10
t = linspace(0, 100/f, 1000);
N = 50;
c = ones(N, 1);
ft = f*t.*c;
s1 = sin(2*pi*ft);
c1 = -cos(2*pi*ft);
r = rand(N,1).*c;
s2 = sin(2*pi*(ft + r));
c2 = -cos(2*pi*(ft + r));
hx = hilbert(s1');
hy = hilbert(s2');
nx = hx./abs(hx);
ny = hy./abs(hy);
p = abs(mean((nx.*conj(ny))'));
grid on
subplot(2, 1, 1)
plot(p)
subplot(2, 1, 2)
plot(c1' - imag(hx))
```

Comment: I think your code differs from what I did though: As far as I understand, you create a random offset for every timepoint once, and then copy that along the N-times. I created a random offset for every 'trial', but this was then held constant along time. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: @a_student Just to clarify: if your random sequence is `[1,5,4]`, then you have `[1, 5, 4; 1, 5, 4; 1, 5, 4]` as the array, while I (could) have `[1, 5, 4; 2, 0, 3; 2, 9, 8]`, i.e. only the first row matches, al the others are random. If that's true, then I will update the code, but I still get a single line.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear before, what I meant is that in my code $x^{k}_{t} = sin(f t + \phi^{k})$, where $k$ is the trial/row, $t$ is the timepoint/column and $\phi^{k}$ is a random phase-offset specific to the trial $k$. Whereas in your (original) code from my understanding  $x^{k}_{t} = sin(f t + \phi_{t})$, i.e. a phase-offset specific to the time-point. Anyway, I do not know too much matlab so maybe I am interpreting it wrong.

Comment: In any case, it seems strange that there would be such a difference... At least the source code of the python function (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.1/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L2169-L2277) looks exactly like the algorithm described in the Matlab documentation (https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hilbert.html)

Comment: If I (finally) understand correctly, and before I modify the answer, `s2` has the 1st row
`[t1+phi1, t2+phi1, t3+phi1, ...]` and the 1st column would be `[t1+phi1; ... t1+phi2; ...
 t1+phi3; ...]`. Is this it?

Comment: yes, that is what i meant

Comment: I think your edit above regarding the spectral leakage is insightful. However, I still do not fully understand why that passes through to the PLV: Intuitively, the error that the leakage introduces in the second signal (s2) should be symmetrical, i.e. zero mean (plot ```plt.plot((c2[:,:100]-hy.imag[:,:100]).T)```) for confirmation). So why does that not cancel out?

Comment: @a_student You're probably judging it visually, looking at the plot, but try to use `np.mean()` on the difference and see what you get. Or plot it, but not all the traces at once, they can be confusing; use one row, only. If one row out of all may have a zero mean, try others, as well. But even if you don't try them out one by one, all, you'll find out that there is no zero mean for the leakage.

Comment: Ok, I've seen that now, I wonder why it does not have 0 mean, but I guess I will have to look more into that to understand it. I will accept you answer now

Comment: @a_student The mean has nothing to do with it: that's just an average over the *entire* sequence, but the multiplying is done point-wise, and the average is done between rows. The result is a vector of a row's length, or of the original signal -- not column length, not an averaged signal. In other words, all the leakages are averaged column-wise, so even if the errors would have been anti-symmetrical, it would not have mattered. Do it with the transposed version, and all you'll see is noise. As for why they exist, it's inherent when dealing with Fourier over finite sequences.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the row-wise mean, i.e. the mean ```np.mean(c2-hy.imag,axis=0)```, that is the mean of the leakage-induced error per time point. But this is also not zero.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the [transposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ6DF.png) difference? Look at the number of samples: 50. That means I am performing the average over the entire signal, and each point from each row is appended to the output vector. As I said: (numerical) noise.